# What is this error, why does it happen?

Tags: android, fragment

```
10-21 13:54:55.337: E/WindowManager(5921): Activity org.acra.CrashReportDialog has leaked window 
com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView{42467520 V.E..... R.....I. 0,0-0,0} that was originally added here
10-21 13:54:55.337: 
E/WindowManager(5921): android.view.WindowLeaked: Activity org.acra.CrashReportDialog has leaked window 
com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView{42467520 V.E..... R.....I. 0,0-0,0} that was originally added here
10-21 13:54:55.337: 
E/WindowManager(5921):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.<init>(ViewRootImpl.java:354)
10-21 13:54:55.337: E/WindowManager(5921):  at 
android.view.WindowManagerGlobal.addView(WindowManagerGlobal.java:216)
10-21 13:54:55.337: E/WindowManager(5921):  at   
android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:69)
10-21 13:54:55.337: E/WindowManager(5921):  at     
android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:281)
10-21 13:54:55.337: E/WindowManager(5921):  at     
org.acra.CrashReportDialog.onCreate(CrashReportDialog.java:76)
10-21 13:54:55.337: E/WindowManager(5921):  at     
android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5104)
10-21 13:54:55.337: E/WindowManager(5921):  at 
android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1080)
10-21 13:54:55.337: E/WindowManager(5921):  at  
android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2144)
10-21 13:54:55.337: E/WindowManager(5921):  at 
android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
10-21 13:54:55.337: E/WindowManager(5921):  at   
android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
10-21 13:54:55.337: E/WindowManager(5921):  at    
android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234)
10-21 13:54:55.337: E/WindowManager(5921):  at  
android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
10-21 13:54:55.337: E/WindowManager(5921):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137) 10-21   
13:54:55.337: E/WindowManager(5921):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
10-21 13:54:55.337: E/WindowManager(5921):     
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-21 13:54:55.337: E/WindowManager(5921):  at  
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
10-21 13:54:55.337: E/WindowManager(5921):  at    
com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
10-21 13:54:55.337: E/WindowManager(5921):  at    
com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
10-21 13:54:55.337: E/WindowManager(5921):  at  
dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: It's due to context..Post your code

Comment: It is due to the context please post the code.

Comment: you are not closing the dialog or closing after activity is finished.

Comment: you have to use progressbardialog.dismiss() at the end of the activity

Comment: can you please tell me what is that context error?

Answer (score 0):

Use below in the initialization of dialog -

```
Dialog mDialog= new Dialog(YourActivityName.this);
```

Answer (score 0):

You're leaking your Window. This happens when your Activity creates the Dialog and you try recreating the Dialog instead of re-using your old dialog/dismiss that previous dialog.